# Problema al acceder a un objeto de un form a otro en delphi

Tags: poo, delphi

Tengo un problema con dos clases en delphi,las tengo de la siguiente manera

```
unit uModuloDatos;

interface
uses
FloguinUsuario;
.
.
.
.
procedure TModuloDatos.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
ConEnc : String;
pedro : TFormLoguinUsuario;
begin
iniconfig:=TConfigIni.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + INIFILENAME);
try
ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Connected:=False;
ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Params.Values['HostName'] := iniconfig.Servidor;
ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Params.Values['port'] := iniconfig.PuertoDatos;
ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationUser']:= 
iniconfig.Usuario;
// Encriptar la contraseña introducida con SHA1
 conenc:='';

**conEnc:=FormLoguinUsuario.EContrasena.Text;** 
if iniconfig.Password<>ConEnc then
begin
  conEnc:=iniconfig.Password; // 40 caracteres
  iniconfig.Save;
 end else
 begin
   conenc:=CalcHash2(ConEnc,haSHA1);
   iniconfig.Password:=ConEnc;
 end;
 // iniconfig.Password:=ConEnc;
 ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationPassword']:= ConEnc;
 ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Connected:=True;
 ConexionServidorDS_Datos.Open;
 iniconfig.Save;

except
 on E: Exception do begin
  MessageDlg('No se puede establecer la conexión con el servicio de 
 datos'+#10#13+
          'Revise los parámetros de conexión',TMsgDlgType.mtError,
 [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK],0);
  Application.Terminate;
 end;
end;
end;
```

Y otra clase de la siguiente manera:
     unit FLoguinUsuario;

```
 interface

 uses
System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, 
System.Variants,
FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
FMX.Objects, FMX.Edit, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient,IdStack,Data.DBXCommon ;

procedure TFormLoguinUsuario.BtnAceptarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
conEnc : String;
iniconfig : TConfigIni;
begin
iniconfig:=TConfigIni.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'config.ini');
// Validar formato de datos introducidos
iniconfig.Servidor:=EServidor.Text;
iniconfig.PuertoDatos:=EPuerto.Text;
iniconfig.Usuario:=EUsuario.Text;
iniconfig.Password:=EContrasena.Text;
if CBRecordarClave.IsChecked then
begin
EContrasena.Text:=iniconfig.Password;
end else
begin
EContrasena.Text:='';
end;
```

Mi problema es que me da un error de INACCESIBLE VALUE en la linea en negrita,intento acceder al valor del edit de la contraseña pero siempre me da 
  INACCESIBLE VALUE y no entiendo por que la verdad,lo tengo todo en public,evidentemente los uses tambien...No se porque no puedo acceder al texto del objeto.

Un saludo!

Comment: No aparece ninguna línea "en negrita" en tu código. ¿El edit al que quieres acceder (que no se cual es) está en la misma unit? ¿En otra? ¿Cual es el nombre?

Comment: Pido disculpas,no se puso en negrita...La linea es esta **conEnc:=FormLoguinUsuario.EContrasena.Text;**  esa es la linea que me da error de INACCESIBLE VALUE,estoy llamando a la propiedad text del objeto edit de otro formulario y asignado su valor a una variable..Pero no se porque me da inaccesible value..@GermánEstévez-Neftalí-

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la parte de interface del formulario TFormLoguinUsuario?
No se ve dónde tienes definida la variable <FormLoguinUsuario> si es que está definida.
Por otro lado, tienes una variable <pedro> privada (de ese mismo tipo). ¿La estás utilizando?
Estamos viendo parte del código y suponiendo otra parte. ¿Podemos verlo todo?

Answer (score 0):

En el la unidad `uModuloDatos` agrega en la clausula `uses` al nombre de la unidad donde se define la variable `FormLoguinUsuario`; funcionara si y solo si `EContrasena` es algún objeto, componente o propiedad definido como público, de manera que sea visible desde otras unidades (units) de tu proyecto de Delphi.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje "Inaccesible Value" no es un error que se esté dando dentro de tu programa, sino un mensaje que estás viendo dentro del depurador de aplicaciones de Delphi (debugger).

Significa que la variable que estás evaluando o siguiendo no tiene una representación en memoria en ese momento y por tanto, no tiene "valor", o su valor es *inaccesible*.

Esto generalmente se debe a la combinación de acciones del *linker* y el *optimizer*, que son parte del compilador.

Estos algoritmos, que se aplican a tu código durante la compilación, tienen como objetivo generar código optimo al hacer la representación en lenguaje máquina de tus algoritmos en Pascal.

Uno de los efectos que tienen ambos (en distintos casos y distintos momentos), es que hay símbolos que no tienen representación en memoria durante determinados momentos del programa, aún cuando se encuentren dentro del contexto (aparente) de ejecución en la representación en Pascal, en realidad están fuera de contexto (no declarados o inaccesibles por alguna otra razón) en el código binario.

Suena muy enredado, pero es fácil de demostrar, y mejor eso intentaré.

Mira este fragmento de código:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  ShowMessage('Hola');
  s := 'Hola2';
  ShowMessage(s);
  s := 'Hola3';
  ShowMessage('Otro hola');
end;
```

Al poner un *breakpoint* en el begin de la rutina, ejecutar y dar clic en el botón, cuando se lanza el IDE de Delphi con el depurador cargado, puedo ver este mensaje "Inaccesible value" en el *Inspector de Variables*, en el *watch* y también en el *tooltip* que aparece si paso el puntero del ratón sobre el nombre de la variable.

Esto es porque esa variable aún no está en uso, y por tanto, en la representación en código máquina, no ha sido "declarada" (y por tanto es inaccesible).

[image: inaccesible al inicio]

Luego, avanzo la ejecución paso a paso, y una vez ocurre la primera asignación de un valor, todo *parece normal*, y lo estará mientras la variable está "en uso real" dentro del programa.

[image: Ahora si podemos ver el valor]

Tan pronto como la variable deja de utilizarse, es probable que el optimizador la *saque de contexto* y con esto esté inaccesible de nuevo.